# Button within Table within Gridview within Sizedbox or Flex is not clickable dependent on other table rows - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am rendering a standard [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) inside a GridView, inside a Flex inside a Row. The 2nd row of the table includes a Button.

When the contents of the first row of the table are above a certain size the clickable region of the button begins to cut off, missing entirely over a certain size.

Note: this is using Flutter Web, I have not tested on Mobile/Desktop.

I have created a minimal reproducible example in an attempt to isolate all logic.

```
 Widget _render() {
    return Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 900,
        height: 900,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: <TableRow>[
              TableRow(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TableCell(
                    child: Text(''),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                      child: SizedBox(
                    height:
                        440, //The clickable region of the button begins to be cut off around 430, and stops altogether by 450
                  ))
                ],
              ),
              TableRow(children: <Widget>[
                TableCell(
                  child: Text(""),
                ),
                TableCell(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(content: Text("Hi Button"))),
                            },
                        child: Text("Hi"))),
              ])
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

What is causing this effect? I am assuming it is some interaction between the visible container and the Table.

Edit: as suggested by @pskink rendered with debugPaintSizEnabled flag which highlights the problem perfectly. However; how would you fix?

- [image]

Comment: Share UI Snippet

Comment: Remove arrow expression. onPressed: () {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(content: Text("Hi Button"))),
                            },

Comment: post your app screenshot with this flag set: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging#debug-flags-layout

Comment: Edited with flag - thanks.

Comment: do you see that bottom horizontal green line? this is a border where you can click above and not allowed to click below

Comment: and most likely it is caused by `GridView.count` parent widget

Comment: You are correct, very clear in hindsight, thanks.